# Parsing "&nbsp;" Characters as Spaces

Tags: php, string, preg-match-all

I'm working on a project for a client where I need to parse data from their legacy HTML pages for more efficient storage. The data appears in this basic format, with multiple key/value pairs on a single line.

```
 Key1: Value1 Key2: Value2...
```

I'm able to get 95% of the records using `preg_match_all('/\w+:\s+\S+/', $line, $items)`

The problem I am having is a minority of the lines contain text like this:

```
 Key1: Value1&nbsp;Key2: Value2
```

In this case, my script shows that Value1 = `Value1&nbsp;Key2:`.

I've tried replacing the `&nbsp;` strings using both `html_entity_decode($line)` and `str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $line)`. With both, I still have `&nbsp;` characters in the output, and the string isn't correctly parsed.

The pages I am trying to parse are WordPress pages. Inspecting the `wp_post` record for the page shows that the `&nbsp;` strings are stored in the database. I believe the pages were populated via an export from MS_Access. Earlier in my script, I've passed the parent of `$line` through `$strip_tags()`.

Is there any reliable way to eliminate/filter/replace this `&nbsp;` string?

Comment: str_replace should work. How are you outputting it?

Comment: If I inspect the output of `echo '<pre>'.print_r($items, true).'</pre>'`, Value1 is incorrect, and the `&nbsp` character is present.

Comment: cpilko - There are many vars you are mentioning and it becomes a bit disconnected. Would help if you can update question with a continuous set of lines in its entirety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been beating my head against the wall for days on this one, and finally found the answer. I tested every answer given by others. None work. -1 for everyone!

The `&nbsp;` is being stored in the database as a Unicode character string. It only shows as `&nbsp;` when rendered in the browser. This removes it.

```
$line = str_replace("\xC2\xA0", " ", $line);
```